# “Just tell a little” vs “Tell just a little” or

Tags: meaning-in-context

> “Tell just a little lie that your heart feels unhappy without me. Once let my heart get pleased then you weasel out again!”

> “Just tell a little lie...”

[image]

I am making a strong request to him tell a little lie that your heart feels unhappy without me.
Which one “Just tell a little lie...” or “Tell just a little lie...” does imply a ‘strong request’ to ask him to do that?

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on you.

**Just tell....** means that all you have to do is to tell a (little) lie. Just a few words are required.

**Tell just....** means that only a little lie is required. It's not a significant lie, just a little white lie.

If you want to emphasise that it's only necessary to speak a few words, use the first. If you want to emphasise that insignificance of the lie, use the second.